# Cross compiling results in relocation error

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

I am attempting to cross-compile (gcc-linaro-9.2.1-2019.12-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf) a code base, on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) x86, targeting Linux (Armbian; 5.8.16 kernel) on ARM. Compilation succeeded, but when I moved the executable/.so's over, I get the error:

```
./myprog: relocation error: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libpthread.so.0: symbol __libc_vfork version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

FWIW I had to copy over `libc.so.6` from the Ubuntu cross-compiler, as the libc on the target ARM machine was too old (libc.so.6 resides in `myprog`'s dir).